# Are "All right, so ....." and "So, yeah, ....." interchangeable when we start to talk about a subject?

Tags: difference, idiomatic-language, colloquial-language, discourse-markers

**"So yeah,...."**

**"All right, so..."**

I sometimes hear these two expressions being used when people start talking about something to other people. For example, I hear that some teachers say **"All right, so"** before they start explaining the subject.

And I also hear people use **"So yeah,..."** when they want to start to talk about a real issue on TV, and it acts as a signal that they want to stop the irrelevant things they are currently talking about, and want to start to talk about the main issue.

But, in the end, they both seem to be used at the start of talking about something. So I wonder are they interchangeable?

Comment: Just a comment: it's better not to copy these. Native speakers don't automatically speak flawless English.

Comment: _PLEASE_ don't get in the habit of starting nearly every sentence with "So..."

Comment: Pretty sure they're saying "alright"!! "All right" is way too formal for a meaningless word whose only purpose is to give the speaker time to collect their thoughts

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are [discourse markers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker), and have no meaning of their own. In that sense, they are interchangeable.

But, having said that, some people can interpret some discourse markers with quite strong social meanings, that are difficult to pin down and define; while others may not notice them at all.

For example, some people object to hearing *So,* at the beginning of an answer, because they think that *so* should only be used to express a consequence of something that has just been said.

For another example, I find an answer starting *Look,* (as many politicans do when being interviewed in the UK) as rather condescending, implying something like "I think this is obvious, and you must be stupid to ask me it". (Of course few politicians would say such things explicitly). Other people may not take the same implication from it as I do.

For these reason, I would not advise using one of these in a different social context from where you heard it.

Comment: Yes. Tony Blair famously uses 'Look'. Some people allege that Nigel Farage uses 'Let me finish!" as a discourse marker.

Comment: I don't necessarily object to hearing ***So,*** at the beginning of an answer. What I find peculiar is people ***starting*** a "conversation" (verbal interaction) with ***So*** when there's no obvious context whereby that initial utterance can be seen as consequence of something that has just been said. Since *nothing* has been said, I'm constantly baffled by what that initial ***So*** is supposed to reference. Quite a few querents here start their questions with ***So***, and I used to think it was just an nns thing, but it's now obvious to me many native Anglophones are doing it too.

Comment: I live in the US midwest, and I can't remember a time in my life when people didn't use "so" like that. It has been entirely common here for at least the last 35 years, and I would be surprised if it hadn't been for much longer than that.

Comment: @yunus Also, note: Since these phrases add nothing to the overall meaning, you might be best off as a learner avoiding them. They often serve no conversational purpose except to hold the speaker's "place in line" while they collect their thoughts (as when the teacher thinks about the best way to start explaining the subject). There's no harm in using something that expresses this directly, like "Let me see...". I often use "a ver..." when I'm speaking Spanish to signal that I'm taking a second to remember the right word to use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers almost any question on Stack Overflow (SO, heh) starting with "so" is likely to be junk. "So I'm trying to do...", "So I'm having a problem...". I think there can be a narrative context to it, like a documentary or recalling some dramatic event - "So, there I was, amid a pack of lions, and..." which _would_ make sense even if the previous conversation was "Tell us about your holiday", which doesn't necessarily link properly. In other words, I think people think it conveys a struggle/hardship through a narrative style

Comment: Whatever phrase is used, if it's used a lot, it can be annoying. Although there are degrees of politeness in such phrases with some being suitable for politicians or lecturers ("all right", "well"), and others for more informal speech ("Hey", "Mmh").

Comment: @roganjosh: I *tend* to agree that questions from native speakers starting with ***So*** are likely to be low quality - but even that is probably more likely to be true if the querent is *older*. Irritated or not, though, we should probably try to avoid such preconceptions if the querent isn't a native speaker in the first place. Even native Anglophone children can often ask "oddly" phrased but relatively penetrating questions. It's just not so promising if you're thinking they should be old enough to communicate more precisely.

Comment: I think that "So..." being used in speech came about because someone was introducing a controversial topic. My daughter uses it extensively when asking for something where she thinks the answer will be "No".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not personally aware of the age bias, and certainly I wouldn't want to discriminate against learners vs. native speakers (who I think are probably _more_ likely to start with "so"). My point was just that I notice that people start posts with "so" when they intend to build some narrative, and it sticks out on SO because, frankly, nobody cares - it's irrelevant to a Q&A site about code. That's why it sticks out so much. I don't dismiss posts off-hand, but it's a good heuristic for what you're in for in the post. I was only addressing why people might use this sentence style

Comment: I've heard it said that every use of "Look, ..." has the word "asshole" implicitly right after it, even if the speaker doesn't say it. In other word, yes, as suggested, it's rather aggressive.

Comment: @roganjosh, JonathanZ: It may be misguided "pop psychology", but to me, *starting* a "conversation" (any verbal interaction) with ***So,*** implies that the speaker (at least subconsciously) assumes his audience are *already* so interested in him and his circumstances that they ***already know*** whatever specific "previous situation or context" has prompted the speaker to open his mouth. So (no pun intended!) it implies the speaker is exceptionally egocentric. In the same vein, initial ***Look*** implies addressee is stupid / inattentive, and is either not looking, or looking the wrong way.

Comment: @roganjosh - So, Mrs Lincoln, how did you like the play?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I missed this notification sorry, but it was _so_ worth it. Kudos; that's given me a proper chuckle :)

Answer (score 3):

"So yeah,...."

"All right, so..."

Both those are discourse markers as pointed out by Colin Fine.

However, **they are used in response to a previous situation or context in conversation**. You normally do not use them ex nihilo.

Also, if you hear a presenter or actor say those at an award ceremony, they are referring to what has just been seen or heard on the stage. That is just an example.

"So yeah" (So, yes is more formal) is much more informal than "All right, so etc."

Comment: Such phrases can also be used (by a teacher, lecturer, etc) to quieten a room or attract attention, or for similar purposes. You might argue that such usages are in response to a situation, but nothing is ex nihilo.

Comment: @StuartF Yes, that would be a prior situation. A way to say: May I have your attention. But you would not be sitting quietly reading in your living room with your spouse who is also reading  and out of the blue (ex nihilo)  say one of those.